# accented characters in String

Tags: sql, diacritics, latin

I have the following characters to be identified as special characters in SQL :

#
¢
£
¥
$
€
Ą
Ę
Ż
Ź
Ć
Ó
α
ß
Γ
δ
ε
Θ
π
µ
Σ
σ
τ
Φ
φ
Ω
Ä
Ë
Ï
Ü

only these characters should be identified as special characters.
Can anyone help me out

Thanks,
naveen

Answer (score 0):

There a good function that I found a long time ago and I use it constantly, it finds all the invisible/weird characters, Try it maybe it will work in your case as well. The way you would do it is, Select dbo.ShowWhiteSpace(Column name)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ShowWhiteSpace] (@str varchar(8000))
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @ShowWhiteSpace varchar(8000);
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = @str
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(32), 'Char(32),[?]')
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(13), '[CR]')
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(10), '[LF]')
     SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(9),  '[TAB]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(1),  '[SOH]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(2),  '[STX]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(3),  '[ETX]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(4),  '[EOT]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(5),  '[ENQ]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(6),  '[ACK]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(7),  '[BEL]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(8),  '[BS]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(11), '[VT]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(12), '[FF]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(14), '[SO]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(15), '[SI]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(16), '[DLE]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(17), '[DC1]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(18), '[DC2]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(19), '[DC3]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(20), '[DC4]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(21), '[NAK]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(22), '[SYN]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(23), '[ETB]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(24), '[CAN]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(25), '[EM]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(26), '[SUB]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(27), '[ESC]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(28), '[FS]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(29), '[GS]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(30), '[RS]')
   SET @ShowWhiteSpace = REPLACE( @ShowWhiteSpace, CHAR(31), '[US]')
     RETURN(@ShowWhiteSpace)
END
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.I dont have the premission to excute :Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'ShowWhiteSpace', database 'dswMM_GEIS', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: in that case, do a manual select of each char() character witha replace 
Select REPLACE(Column , CHAR(29), '[GS]') from .... 

or you can come up with a while loop to check each char() character for all the rows in tables.